# Set a text in the drawing area

Tags: python, pygtk, pango

I'd like to set a text into Drawing Area object, using pygtk. 
So, I created a drawing area and set up a callback function using "expose event" signal. 
Then I coded a function to set the text. 
What I coded is:

```
self.pangolayout = self.movie_window.create_pango_layout("")
...
self.pangolayout.set_text("Text here")
```

where "movie_windows" is a DrawingArea object. 
I got no error, but nothing is written on the drawing area. 
SuggestionS?

FB

Comment: Can you put the complete code, or a minimal part of code that can run?

Answer (score 0):

Did you draw the layout to the window?

The third example of this tutorial uses pango layout: 
http://zetcode.com/tutorials/pygtktutorial/pangoII/